# random numbers being read into array instead of the text file values

Tags: arrays, c, txt

I am trying to make a function that reads all the numbers from a text file into an array, where each line of the file has a number, ex:

```
57346
40963
24580
98307
98312
32777
10
16392
16396
...
```

My function does allocate the necessary size to store the values, but the values being stored are random ones and 0's that aren't in my text file. Output ex:

```
0
0
296386
0
-485579776
-653048057
584
0
2095946880
...
```

This is my code:

```
typedef struct set{
    void** values;
    int size; 
}Set;
```

```
int checkSize(FILE* file) { 
    int counter = 0;
    char chr;
    chr = getc(file);

    while (chr != EOF) {
        if (chr == '\n') {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        chr = getc(file);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

```
Set* readSet(FILE* file){ 
    Set* new = malloc(sizeof(Set));
    new->size = checkSize(file);
    new->values = malloc(sizeof(void*)*new->size);
    int arrayAux[new->size];
    int i = 0, n;
    
    while(i < new->size) {
        fscanf(file, "%ld", &arrayAux[i]);
        new->values[i] = arrayAux[i];
        i++;
    }
    
    //loop to remove the first three lines of the file, which are the number of values in the file,
    //the biggest value of the file and the division between the number of values and the biggest value
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {   
            new->values[i] = new->values[i + 1];
            new->size--;
        }
    for (i = 0; i <= new->size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", new->values[i]);
    }

    
    return new;
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why `void**` and not `int *` for the `values` field? Since you are storing `int` values and not pointers. Also, Please show the code that prints the results. That is, provide a complete [mre] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You need to `rewind` the file after calling `checkSize` as the file pointer will be at the end of the file.

Comment: `checkSize` reads to the end of the file so there's nothing for `fscanf` to read. Check the return value so you know if it succeeded or failed. `chr` should also be an `int`.

Comment: One of the things you should have investigated during debugging is whether the problem is (1) the values were read correctly and stored into the array, but came out corrupted when you tried to print them; or (2) the values were never read correctly in the first place. That will tell you which part of the program you need to focus on.

Comment: `"%ld"` requires a pointer to a `long` variable. But you are providing `&arrayAux[i]` which is a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: SLightly OT: `char chr;` should be `int chr;`. Otherwise a byte with value 255 might be mistaken for an EOF.

Comment: ... or a returned EOF (-1) might be mistaken for a 255. Both ways are wrong and you need to use correct types.

Answer (score 0):

Why void and not long?

You cannot do int arrayAux[new->size]; as size is a variable and thus cannot be used at compile time !!! 100% guarantee of reading out of bounds.
Read the value from file into a long and assign it to the proper space in your list.

Why have the size in every row? Use a global int

why loop to step over the first three in the list?
size -=3
i+=3
Works just as well